# Reformulate custom predicate as std-predicate

Tags: c++

A program I'm working on contains this predicate struct:

```
struct Unlike {
    Unlike(const Vertex& in) : a(in) {}
    bool operator()(const Vertex& b) {
        return !(a==b);
    }
    const Vertex& a;
};
```

Vertices are structs with (among other members) a struct coord with members X, Y, Z. Comparison is done with these functions:

```
bool operator==(const Vertex& a, const Vertex& b) {
    bool res =  a.coord.X == b.coord.X &&
        a.coord.Y == b.coord.Y &&
        a.coord.Z == b.coord.Z;
    return res;
}
inline bool operator!=(const Vertex& a, const Vertex& b) {
    bool res = !(a==b);
    return res;
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
// Fill and sort vertices
std::vector<Vertex>::iterator vcur, vnext;
vcur = vertices.begin();
while(vcur != vertices.end()) {
    vnext = std::find_if(vcur, vertices.end(), Unlike(*vcur));
    // Loop over [vcur, vnext]
    vcur = vnext;
}
```

So we perform some calculations on all vertices which compare equal.

I'm doing some cleaning in the code, and would like to get rid of the `Unlike` struct. I tried to do it like this, which to my mind is clearer in intent:

```
vnext = std::adjacent_find(vcur, vertices.end(), std::not_equal_to<Vertex>());
```

but that did not retain the same behavior, but rather goes into an infinite loop. Why? Have I misinterpreted `adjacent_find` or `not_equal_to`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

std::adjacent_find  **looking ahead for one item**  and returns iterator if predicate is true.

(1) For example, if you  use not_equal_to for the list of two letters
    ['a','b'] and your current iterator points to 'a' then predicate
    will be positive because 'a' not equal to the **next** 'b' and std::adjacent_find 
    returns an iterator which is a reference to 'a'.

(2) in your first version find_if first iterate to 'b' and  only then compare 'b' with
    'a'. And as result we have an iterator which is a reference to 'b'.

Comment: Hm, so I'd want to increment the iterator from `adjacent_find`? Except that that will eventually go past the end, so it is not an alternative either...

Comment: In any case, std::adjacent_find is not what you need.
May be this, 
vnext = std::find_if(vcur, vertices.end(),   bind2nd(not_equal_to<Vertex>(), *vcur))

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have a recommendation for another `std::find*` approach?